# How to parse AppsFlyer Conversion Data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, appsflyer-cordova-sdk

How to parse this response:

> {af_sub1=1.5, af_deeplink=true, campaign=None, media_source=None,
>   install_time=2018-05-08 03:34:34, af_status=Non-organic, path=,
>   scheme=, host=}

as result of following code:

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
     console.log(result);
};

window.plugins.appsFlyer.initSdk(options,onSuccess,onError);
```

It's look like JSON, but using `=` instead of `:`, then I tried to parse it using `result.af_sub1` and `result["af_sub1"]`, both return `undefined`

Comment: fixed in v4.4.8. See ticket: https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/cordova-plugin-appsflyer-sdk/issues/31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first transform the response to conform to JSON and then parse it using `JSON.parse`. See the snippet below. Note that all data types will be strings and you need to take care of data type conversions yourself. I.e. `af_deeplink` will not be a boolean.

```js
let result = "{af_sub1=1.5, af_deeplink=true, campaign=None, media_source=None,install_time=2018-05-08 03:34:34, af_status=Non-organic, path=, scheme=, host=}";

let parseResponse = (res) => JSON.parse(res.replace(/([^,\s\{=]+)=([^,]*)(?=,|\})/gi, '"$1" : "$2"'));
let obj = parseResponse(result);

console.log(typeof obj);  // object
console.log(obj.af_sub1); // 1.5
```

PS: For detailed explanations on the used regular expression please refer to [the snippet](https://regex101.com/r/M6KD09/1) I created on regex101.com